# How can I make my local workspace work offline on another machine?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I'm using a local worspace for my projects because the documentaiton: [Decide between using a local or a server workspace](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/decide-between-using-local-server-workspace) states it is possible to work offline with it:

> Work offline easily. You can quickly begin editing a file when your
>   network connection is unavailable or unreliable. From Solution
>   Explorer you can add, edit, delete, rename, undo, and compare items in
>   your workspace even when you're not connected to your Team Foundation
>   Server.

However I'm not going to work offline on the same machine. I take home a copy on a flash drive and I'd like to continue there.

Unfortunatelly when I open the copy at home Visual Studio says the bindings could not be found and it will open the solution as it wasn't under source control:

> The solution appears to be under source control, but its binding
>   information cannot be found. Because it is not possible to recover
>   this missing information automatically, the projects whose bindings
>   are missing will be treated as not under source control.

Why doesn't the copy work offline? Do I need to somehow fake the TFS connection in my Visual Studio at home?

Answer (score 0):

You've misunderstood work offline. When you work offline, you need to still work on your local workspace. In this way, when you connect to TFS, TFS will be able to detect the pending changes. If you copy the solution/project to another machine with a flash drive, TFS won't able to detect changes.

For your scenario, you have following options to choose:

1. Take the PC from office to home, and still work on the same PC. You can work offline, when you back to office, connect to TFS, TFS will detect the changes automatically.
2. Connect to TFS and create a new workspace on the PC which is at home. Then you can work on your own PC. When back to office, get latest code from TFS to continue working.
3. Replace the changes you work at home on your office PC, when you back to office.

Comment: Options 1 & 2 are not possible for me - that's why I picked the 3rd one. I copy my work back to the flash drive and take it with me to work where I restore it. The problem is that at home (I cannot connect to the tfs) VS won't accept the fact that I want to work offline and refuses to track changes with the above message.

Comment: Go to File--Source Control--Advanced--Change Source Control to unbind the project at home.